# Remove copy.com cloud client

Tags: uninstall

I tried copy.com cloud client on my Lubuntu. I can't find any instructions how to remove it. Any idea?

Maybe this instructions for installation will helps someone:
https://copy.zendesk.com/entries/24061068-How-do-I-install-Copy-for-Linux-

Comment: The install instructions don't indicate anything about how it installs unfortunately. It seems the program installs itself when you run it. Can you run these in Terminal and see if they provide any useful information? : `CopyCmd -help` & `man CopyCmd`

Comment: Tnx, "CopyCmd -help"  shows me the way :-)

Answer (score 2):

open terminal in the installation folder of Copy and type:

```
sudo ./CopyCmd overlay remove
```

This should uninstall the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

I closed my account and emailed them to find out how to remove it. I am guessing it worked as it does not start up anymore, nor does it show up in the startup apps window.

Open up a new terminal window and type this command: (It will terminate CopyAgent)

```
pkill CopyAgent
```

Then once that's done:

```
rm -rf ~/.copy
```

You may then delete your Copy folders, Copy will then be completely removed from your computer.**

Answer (score 0):

For reference, if anyone comes here.

At the terminal paste: `/path/to/your/copy/folder/CopyCmd overlay remove`

You can see a list of commands running just `/path/to/your/copy/folder/CopyCmd`

Comment: Need to specify the module `Overlay` before `remove` otherwise you just get the list of commands.