# Uninstall Copy.com from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: cloud, online-storage, copy.com

I have installed the cloud storage program, "Copy" and want to uninstall it. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at [this similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/391418/remove-copy-com-cloud-client)?

Answer (score 19):

Follow these steps to completely remove Copy from your system:

1. Disable autostart for each user, if necessary.  (You don't need to use `sudo` if no other user accounts on your system are using Copy)...

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /home/<user>/.config/autostart/CopyAgent.desktop
   ```
2. Log out and log back in.  This will shut down the running copy process so it does not re-create the files you are about to delete in step 3.  (You can also just kill the "CopyAgent" process using System Monitor if you don't want to log out.)
3. Execute the following for each user, if necessary.  (You don't need to use `sudo` if no other user accounts on your system are using Copy).

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /home/<user>/<path_to_users_copy_folder>/.copy.cache/
   sudo rm -rf /home/<user>/<path_to_users_copy_folder>/.user_info
   sudo rm -rf /home/<user>/.copy
   sudo rm -rf /home/<user>/.icons
   ```
4. If you had *manually* installed the Nautilus overlay icons, uninstall them...

   ```
   sudo <installation_location>/<architecture>/CopyCmd Overlay remove
   ```
5. Uninstall Copy software...

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /root/.copy
   ```
6. If you had *manually* added a launcher shortcut, remove it.  Assuming you called the launcher "copy.desktop" do the following.

   For all users...

   ```
   sudo rm  /usr/share/applications/copy.desktop
   ```

   Or, for each user...

   ```
   sudo rm  /home/<user>/.local/share/applications/copy.desktop
   ```

Note, in the above steps...

- Replace `<user>` with the user on your system that is using Copy.
- Replace `<path_to_users_copy_folder>` with the user's local "Copy" folder (for example, `Documents/Copy`).
- Replace `<installation_location>` with the location where you
  installed Copy (for example `/usr/share/copy`).
- Replace `<architecture>` with "`x86`" (if you have a 32bit computer) or with
  "`x86_64`" (if you have a 64bit computer).

Comment: I just want to warn that if you manually installed some icon themes into your ~/.icons folder, be careful not to delete them in the step 3 along with the copy-*.svg icons.

Answer (score 1):

`cd` to the Copy installation directory where `CopyAgent` and `CopyCmd` are present

And then enter
`sudo ./CopyCmd overlay remove`

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall open terminal by press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in a keyboard, then copy this following to terminal window

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove copy
```

Comment: If it was not installed as an Ubuntu package or .deb, apt-get won't work to uninstall it.